# Java regex remove tabs and replace it with 1 whitespace.

Tags: java, regex, replace, trim

```
for(String s1 :splitedString){


listOfWords.add(s1.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "").replace("\t"," ").replace("\\s+", " ").trim());
            }
```

So this replaces all the tabs with, 
So words like 
ABCD  AAAAA
become 
ABCDAAAAA
and I want 
ABCD AAAAA

Comment: `.replaceAll("\\s+", " ")`

Comment: yeah, I just got it.  
replaceAll instead of just replace